# Homeassistant Timezone Sync

Tags: home-assistant

My raspi knows when EDT (Eastern US Daylight Time) is active,

```
HypriotOS/armv7: pirate@black-pearl in ~
$ date
Thu Oct 17 10:27:27 EDT 2019
```

the docker container for homeassistant knows when EDT is active,

```
root@black-pearl:/# date
Thu Oct 17 10:28:54 EDT 2019
```

but I cannot manage to get homeassistant v.0.100.2 to reflect this.

I've used

```
time_zone: EST
```

which does display the correct time if I were NOT in daylight savings.

Here's what else Ive tried:

1. passing in the hosts time, which clearly works as evidenced by the docker containers console

   ```
   -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime

   -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
   ```
2. Leaving  blank in the hopes that [freegeoip will solve this for me](https://www.home-assistant.io/blog/2015/05/09/utc-time-zone-awareness/#setting-up-your-time-zone).
3. Using time_zone: EDT instead of EST but it isn't recognized as a valid config.

Ultimately I'm not above lying to hass and telling it we're in      America/Moncton (UTC - 4) and manually switching it back to EST (UTC - 5) the night before our transitions, but thats not really in the spirit of automation so I'd rather not.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
America/New_York
```

SOLVED

this worked. im a dingus. if i knew how to read and FOLLOW DIRECTIONS i would have read to use tz_database_name instead of its common abbreviation.

credit to reddits u/kb5zuy